# C++ construct detached thread to avoid deadlock

Tags: c++, multithreading, deadlock

I have a timer class `Timer` with a function `start`, a function `stop` and a virtual function `tick`. Calling `start` will create a thread that runs an infinite loop and calls `tick` every x seconds. Calling `stop` will stop the loop and join this thread.

I derived a class `DerivedTimer` from `Timer` and implemented the `tick` function. Then I got this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Resource deadlock avoided
```

The reason was that somewhere down the line, the `stop` function is called in the implementation of `tick`. This obviously does not work, since it´s trying to join its own thread.

Now I´m trying to find a way, how to stop the `DerivedTimer` from within its `tick` function so that I can stop the `DerivedTimer` until it can be started again.

I thought of calling stop from another detached thread. Like this:

```
std::thread t(&DerivedTimer::stop, this);
t.detach();
```

I am not 100% sure if this could go wrong in any situation. My fear is that, since a thread is started upon construction, stop is executed and it´s trying to join the thread before `t` was detached. Could this happen? If yes, is there another solution? Can I somehow create a thread and detach it before it´s starting to execute?

Comment: a thread must be joined axactly once from the thread that created it, so calling stop() and thereby join() from within the thread itself can't work.

if your trigger to stop comes from withing the main thread, you need some thread safe thing (semaphore or else) to be queried by the sub thread's worker tick() or its calling function.

if the trigger to leave comes from withing tick(), just give back some bool to make the subthread's worker function to return. The mainthread could in this case call join() directly after the thread's launch and will thus block until the subthread returns.

Comment: i forgot: join() does NOT end the thread: it just WAITs until it ends.

Comment: @Synopsis thank you but this not exactly what I asked for. I am aware of how threads and joining a thread works. I‘m searching for a way to end a thread from within the same thread.

Comment: @Synopsis calling stop from a detached thread works and is exactly what I‘m looking for. But I‘m afraid that in some edge cases it gets to the call of join before the thread is detached

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your code. The question is unclear, because a thread basically just executes a function call and the thread finishes when that function returns.

Comment: " stop is executed and it´s trying to join the thread before t was detached." this is unclear. Either you detach a thread or you join it but not both

Comment: You could have `stop` detect if it is being called from the timer's own thread and raise a custom `StopException` that you can catch at the top of the thread?

Comment: A thread ends when the thread function returns. Sounds like the thread function here is running an infinite loop; to end the thread, just exit from the loop and return from the function.

Comment: Suppose for a moment that you somehow figured out a way for `tick` to cause the original thread to join the spawned thread. (That is, suppose you had the perfect answer to the question as asked.) Then what happens? The original thread will wait for the spawned thread to finish. What is supposed to cause the spawned thread to finish? (The answer is not to call `join`, as that has no effect on the spawned thread finishing.)

Comment: @PeteBecker thank you, I forgot to write. Yes it runs an infinite loop that loop executes ´tick´ and ´stop´ stops the loop in the next run and joins the thread. I have to join it, otherwise it results in undefined behavior

Comment: I decided to use another workaround. I added a function ´pauseExecution´, the loop will keep running but does not execute ´tick´. So I don´t have to call ´stop´ and therefore won´t need to join the thread

Comment: @tjaehnig -- if you've detached the thread you cannot join it.